# why my form (radio) checked the last element by default in laravel collective

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravelcollective

i dont know why my ***radio button*** checked by default the last element in laravel collective,in my case the radio button is using for select gender,each element contain representative of the gender as alphabet 'L' or 'P',thank in advance,

```
    <div class="form-group">
      {{-- <label for="jenisKelamin" class="control-label">Jenis Kelamin</label> --}}
        {{Form::label('jenisKelamin','Jenis Kelamin',['class'=>'control-panel'])}}

        <div class="form-check">
            {{-- <label>
            <input type="radio" name="jenisKelamin" id="jenisKelamin" value="L" class="form-control" placeholder="Jenis Kelamin" >Laki-Laki</label> --}}
            {{Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','L',['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}
            <label class="form-check-label">Laki-Laki</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            {{Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','P',['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}
            <label class="form-check-label">Perempuan</label> 
        </div>
        </div>
            @if($errors->has('jenis_kelamin'))
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('jenis_kelamin') }}</div>

        @endif
    </div><br>
```

Comment: It would help if you were to translate it to english. I understand 'jenis_kelamin' means 'gender'. Also, can you show us the raw HTML output?

Comment: i'm sorry @JorisJ1 [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sLFTurBCrtqVwrByIs8-rZM5X1lX8F5q) it is the image , and at the image the first radio named laki laki it means male and the second is female, i hope that help you to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the `laravelcollective/html` package. When I view the raw HTML output in my internet browser, this is what I see:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="jenisKelamin" class="control-panel">Jenis Kelamin</label>
  <div class="form-check">
        <input checked="checked" name="jenis_kelamin" type="radio" value="L">
        <label class="form-check-label">Laki-Laki</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input checked="checked" name="jenis_kelamin" type="radio" value="P">
        <label class="form-check-label">Perempuan</label> 
    </div>
</div>
</div><br>
```

Both radio input's are checked (have `checked="checked"`). Since both have the same name, meaning only one can be checked at a time, only the last is checked on screen.

Let's look at the source for the `Form::radio` function. It can be found in `\vendor\laravelcollective\html\src\FormBuilder.php` in your project, or in the [Github repository](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/b3b35b61433e77d8673e51e3b99183d2db4621c1/src/FormBuilder.php#L865). Here we see the function has this header:

```
public function radio($name, $value = null, $checked = null, $options = [])
```

It seems the third argument should be a boolean value determing the checked status, and any additional options as the fourth argument. This is also shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md).

In your snippet it would look like this:

```
{{Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','L', true, ['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}
{{Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','P', false, ['class'=>'form-check-input'])}}
```

Comment: Is there no easier way than adding parameters that have the same value (false)

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Personally, I would not use `laravelcollective/html` at all but regular HTML instead combined with blade tags `@if` and such.

Answer (score 1):

If that can help, because I have been looking for a while before finding

```
{{ Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','L', true, ['class'=>'form-check-input', 'id' => 'id_l']) }}
{{ Form::label('id_l', 'Laki-Laki', ['class' => 'form-check-label']) }}

{{ Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','P', '', ['class'=>'form-check-input', 'id' => 'id_p']) }}
{{ Form::label('id_p', 'Perempuan', ['class' => 'form-check-label']) }}
```

On the Radio Input, before the options array, add an empty option '' or 'true' for selecting by default.
Work on V 5.7 and 6